# Gradient transition works in IE

Tags: html, css, background, transition, gradient

I am making an HTML Application (`hta`) on windows. I went to make a linear gradient background transition, when I realized that gradients don't have any transitions, but I decided that I would put my mind to it and do it anyway. I had made a simple animation, but when I opened the app, it worked! I have to say IE has the transition I want for linear gradients. This is what I want my background to be:

```css
body {
  animation: animat 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes animat {
    0% {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen, lightblue);}
    50% {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightblue, lightgreen);}
    100% {background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen, lightblue);}
}
```

Anyway, that gives this cool effect in IE, where it is soothing, but you can't tell the background is necessarily moving. I would appreciate it if someone could open this page in IE and let me know how to do it **without** background-position. Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: can you share a gif taken from IE?

Comment: Please specify IE version.

Comment: This is IE 11 and I will update with a video